# calculate days from different number of dates python

Tags: python

For a particular user having number of dates, I want to calculate total number of days bewteen two dates. Here the problem is a particular user has around 5 dates at random interval and I want to calculate frequency for the user. For two dates I know how to calculate but dont know for number of dates.

data looks like:
`[datetime.date(2016, 1, 1) datetime.date(2016, 3, 25)
 datetime.date(2016, 4, 15)]` and I want to calculate total number of gaps between dates.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What would be the expected output for your example?

Comment: If there are three separate dates wouldn't there be two *gaps*?

Comment: So you want the number of days between the first and last date, without the days where there is a date in your list?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Unfortunately this isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.  Invest some time with [the Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) practicing the examples. It will give you an idea of the tools Python offers to help you solve your problem.

Comment: for  the data shown above the final output is 105 days.logic is as var a= date[0][2]-date[0][1]. Var b= date[0][1]-date[0][0]. print(a+b).

Comment: @wwii I know coding in python. If you cant help then dont mock. Rest of the coders will try to help atleast.

Comment: So your problem is just to find the difference between the first and last date...

Comment: No mocking intended, sorry you took it that way. I seriously believe that if you are familiar with the contents of the Tutorial and the docs for the datetime module you would be able to make good attempt at solving the problem and maybe come back to ask questions about specific problems you have with your solution.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you need the diff between the date in your list. You can iterate over the list and use `enumerate`

```
import datetime
l = [datetime.date(2016, 1, 1), datetime.date(2016, 3, 25), datetime.date(2016, 4, 15)]
leng = len(l)
res = 0
for i,v in enumerate(l):
    if i+1 == leng:
        break
    else:
        res += (l[i+1] - v).days 
print(res)
```

**Output:**

```
105
```

Answer (score 1):

Given that you need the difference between the first and last date (the list doesn't need to be sorted), you can just do:

```
from datetime import date

days = [date(2016, 1, 1), date(2016, 3, 25), date(2016, 4, 15)] 

print (max(days) - min(days)).days    #Prints 105
```

As it doesn't matter how many dates are in the middle, the result will be the same as `(days[2] - days[1]) + (days[1] - days[0])`. As you can see the `days[1]` cancels out and the result is just `days[2] - days[0]` in the sorted list.

---

#### Below is my original answer to which I thought the average between each day was needed

Given that the days list is sorted, you can use the [pairwise recipe](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes) that uses [`itertools.tee`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.tee) to create a generator that grabs all the differences for you then get the arithmatic mean in days from the result.

```
from datetime import date
from itertools import tee

days = [date(2016, 1, 1), date(2016, 3, 25), date(2016, 4, 15)] 

def pairwise(iterable):
    "s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ..."
    a, b = tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return zip(a, b)

def mean(numbers):
    numbers = list(numbers)
    return float(sum(num.days for num in numbers)) / max(len(numbers), 1)

pairs = pairwise(days)                # Returns [(datetime.date(2016, 1, 1), datetime.date(2016, 3, 25)), (datetime.date(2016, 3, 25), datetime.date(2016, 4, 15))]
diff = list(b - a for a, b in pairs)  # Returns [datetime.timedelta(84), datetime.timedelta(21)]
print mean(diff)                      # Returns 52.5
```